# Outlook text disappearing when typing in different lines

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I am facing an issue in Outlook client (office 365) in windows 10 PC.

Not sure why but when I create a "new email" and type text inside the body box the text "disappears".

What happens is that I can see the text when I am writing it but when I press the "Enter"/return key, I am taken into the next line and I stop seeing what I written in the previous lines. From what I can see I can only see the text which is written in the current line (last line) although I know that the text is in the previous lines as well. So I am sure the text is not being erased.

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the latest Office365 patch update.

Follow these instructions: https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/na7h69/outlook_2016_text_in_the_body_is_disappearing/

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me Microsoft launched an update which solve this issue. Thanks